# Django manage.py created outsite the project folder

Tags: python, django

I started a django project using this command

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

then I got folder mysite in the current folder(madhu131313).
In madhu131313 folder I got mysite and again in mysite I got another mysite folder .
In the top *mysite* folder I got manage.py folder and in the inner *mysite* folder I have **init**.py ,settings.py ,urls.py ,wsgi.py .But according to the instructor I am following ( in two books I am following ) He got mysite directory in that he had **init**.py ,manage.py,settings.py ,urls.py .

Can anyone tell why this happened .I am using python 2.7

Sorry if I go wrong anywhere ,I am new to the site and a beginner in django

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you've described is normal behaviour for django 1.4: the outer mysite is the project name and the inner one is your "main" package.

maybe you are following old instructions, i.e. for an old django version?